# Python3 - Dynamically calling variables in a loop and writing into file

Tags: python-3.x

I have some of variables I would like to write in a file. Since they are pretty much well ordered (01,12 etc) I want to put them inside a loop.

For that, one needs to convert the variable result into a string. The problem is that if I do that, I'll write the very same string that is my variable name (and not my variable result, converted to string).

```
r01=func_dif(t0g,t1g)   
r23=func_dif(t2g,t3g)
r34=func_dif(t3g,t4g)
r45=func_dif(t4g,t5g)
r56=func_dif(t5g,t6g)
r67=func_dif(t6g,t7g)

a = 0
b = 1

with open('script2Out', 'w') as f:
    for a in range(7):
        f.write('r{}{} = {} \n'.format(a,b,str(f'r{a}{b}')))
        a += 1
        b += 1
```

As you have probably guessed, here is what I get

```
r01 = r01 
r12 = r12 
r23 = r23 
r34 = r34 
r45 = r45 
r56 = r56 
r67 = r67
```

Whereas I wish to get something like (my variable results are lists)

```
r01 = [5.24,21,74,95,66]
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using python's eval() function:

```
a = 0
b = 1

with open('script2Out', 'w') as f:
    for a in range(7):
        f.write('r{}{} = {} \n'.format(a,b,str(eval('r{a}{b}'))))
        b += 1
```

Comment: `locals()[...]` / `globals()[...]` is always a safer option than `eval`

Comment: Either is fine here